# Run-time error 3219 when trying dbs.OpenRecordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, dao

Normally I use ADODB recordsets and database connections, but i am required to use DAO record sets for the first time due to some limitations of ADO. I am attempting to create a recordset and i am receiving error 3219 - Invalid Operation.

Here is all my DAO database code.

`Dim dbsTrace As DAO.Database
Dim rsTrace As DAO.Recordset`

`Set dbsTrace = CurrentDb
Set rsTrace = dbsTrace.OpenRecordset("TRACE", dbOpenTable)`

The error is throwing on the last line. This code was taken directly from the msdn.microsoft website and then modified to include my table name...

Thoughts?

Comment: Change `dbOpenTable` to `dbOpenDynaset`.

Comment: Had to add ("TRACE",dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges). Because my table is a connection to a SQL Server table. Just curious, why did dbOpenTable not work but dbOpenDynaset works? What's the difference

Comment: I think `dbOpenTable` is for local tables only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change dbOpenTable to dbOpenDynaset. Credit to Kostas K. in comments.

NOTE: Also had to add dbSeeChanges option due to the fact that i was using a sql server table connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only need the table in a read only recordset simply use dbOpenSnapshot, this will give you a un-editable recordset copy at the time.